# <br> tag not working in appended textarea jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, textarea, line-breaks

I am saving the value in the database with the `<br>` tag when I try to fetch that data and printing the data value in appended textarea as a value, there is not line break that happens and directly printing `<br>` tags.
I also check to append the value in `alert()` then kit showing the line break but when I set the value in the textbox that same code, not line breaking.
Please help me how to fix this, I also check all the code and threads available on StackOverflow but it did not work for me.

```
//$("textarea#textarea").val().replace("<br>", "\n"); //not worked

//alert($("textarea#textarea").val().replace("<br>", "\n")); //worked
```

I am using this function in append textarea, a sort code I am mentioning below -

```js
//after ajax success response...

var len = response.data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  $("textarea#textarea").val('');
  $("textarea#textarea").val(response.data[i]['address']);
  $("textarea#textarea").val().replace("<br>", "\n");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please help me how to I fix this issue -

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing replaced word in textarea. Use the below code.

```
var len = response.data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  $("textarea#textarea").val('');
  $("textarea#textarea").val(response.data[i]['address']);
  $("textarea#textarea").val($("textarea#textarea").val().replace("<br>", "\n"));
}
```

or shortly

```
var len = response.data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  $("textarea#textarea").val(response.data[i]['address'].replace("<br>", "\n"));
}
```

Comment: please help. why this is not working in mycase

Comment: in output in simply showing `<br>` tag.. it not replacing in new line break

Comment: Try regex ```$("textarea#textarea").val(response.data[i]['address'].replace(/<br>/g, "\n"));```

Comment: It is working... Pls help me.. saving tags in database is bad practice.. at the time of inserting textarea data in db, i am using this code `
$address = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['vendoraddress'])));
$address = str_replace("\n", '<br>', $address); `
How I save the tag in encode way ? will your code work after encode to decode when retrive from DB. ??

Comment: if you decode it the correct way it will work